# Can I use Meteor to develop for Android without KVM?

Tags: android, meteor, kvm

all.  When I install the android sdk for meteor, I get a complaint that I don't have kvm enabled (1st quote).  When I check whether my cpu supports kvm, I am told no (2nd quote).  Am I just stuck?  Do I have to buy a new laptop, or forget using meteor for android?  Regards, Rick

```
> rick@rick-Inspiron-1750:~/work/141202/simple-todos$ meteor install-sdk
> android✓ Found Android bundle
>      :      :  Creating android virtual device (AVD): meteor  ✓ 'meteor' android virtual device (AVD) created ✗ Android emulator
> acceleration is not installed   (The Android emulator will be very
> slow without acceleration) Platform requirements not yet met          
> Please follow the instructions here:          
> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux#haxm
> 
> 
> rick@rick-Inspiron-1750:~/work/141202/simple-todos$ sudo
> /usr/sbin/kvm-ok INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions KVM
> acceleration can NOT be used
> rick@rick-Inspiron-1750:~/work/141202/simple-todos$
```

Comment: `The Android emulator will be very slow without acceleration` this is the only downside of not having HAXM... you can always use real device for debuging

Comment: Thanks, @Selvin.  For the next guy who has the same question:  I plunged ahead and tried running the emulator.  It is indeed several minutes to come up and look like an android phone.  But it does work. 

I never saw my app.  The app is available from ricks_app.meteor.com same as always, but never came up on the simulated phone.  Should I expect it to come up on the phone?  Is there some other step I should be taking once the simulated phone is up?

Comment: You can wait fro some time. It will start up automatically. Else u can press the recent app button (the one on the right) in the android simulator.